# Reference/textbook on RAM model/model of computation for algorithms

Tags: computation-models

Can someone recommend a reference/textbook on the RAM model of computation? Preferably something with a concise definition and doesn't get too much into computer architecture. I'm very fine with this is the RAM model this is how much time space,... accept it.

There seems to be some inconsistency as to whether or not the RAM model has a CPU with registers in addition to memory and whether the memory access is free.

Also, should there be some other space requirements when it comes to storing/accessing variables or is that somehow free in this model? If I have many variables, then I also need to store the index/location of each variable. Would the machine need to search the memory for the location of where variables are stored? or is that also somehow free?

I've only been able to find a detailed description of the word RAM model however I'm not sure why the main memory needs to be partitioned into words of a certain size.
I'm  also looking for a textbook/notes on the word ram model.

Comment: You can check [Boaz Barak's notes](https://introtcs.org/public/lec_07_other_models.html) from his new textbook.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus  He just seems to skim over the RAM model though

Also is the RAM and word RAM model the same?

Comment: The RAM model has several variants, the most common being the word RAM.